# Flurry Analytics, Basic Analytics Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, analytics

Does anyone have any experience using the basic analytics services with the Flurry Analytics SDK?

I have two applications which I am testing this out with. Both are existing apps which I added the Flurry SDK to and set up to track basic events -- the apps were updated and went live in the app store about 16 hours ago. I know there have been users, I myself have used the updated version extensively.

The problem is that the Flurry dashboard shows no new users, no events tracked, nothing at all. The only information in my Flurry dashboard is 1 new user which was me testing the service one week again before I submitted to Apple.

I have the relevant files and library imported in my project for Flurry. In my AppDelegat.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method I have:

```
[FlurryAnalytics startSession:@"MY_APP_KEY"];
```

When I want to log events I am using:

```
[FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"EVENT_NAME"];
```

Pretty standard stuff, but it doesn't seem to ever track it or update it. Anyone have any experience with this? How often does it update the web dashboard? Am I doing something totally wrong?

Comment: what is this "logEvent" stands for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may sometime take Flurry long before it updates new data initially. When I first set up my app with Flurry, it took hours before my first test data was reflected.

I'd suggest to wait a bit longer, and if there is still no data, contact the Flurry support.

Actually you can contact them right now and ask for the issues, theres no harm in that. But I guess they are only going to ask you to wait.

Comment: Well it has been about 20 hours now, and no update. The use of the words 'Real Time' analytics on their site is slightly misleading then if it takes more than a day to update. I have contacted their support, no response.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem when testing Flurry using the simulator or the device from Xcode.
The problem was that I was killing the app from Xcode right after testing and sending events, and no data was sent to Flurry server.

Data is only sent to the server when the application goes into background, so press the home button and wait 10 seconds before killing your app.

You can also enable debug log and see when data is sent and if response is correct (http code=200):

```
[Flurry setDebugLogEnabled:YES];
```

It can take a couple of hours for data being visible in Flurry reports.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am Using flurry in my game. Just wait for **3 or 4 days** and you will see the data.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and contacted support. They said:

> Although the Flurry SDK sends data from the devices to our servers on
>   an almost real-time basis, there could be a delay in reporting ranging
>   from 5 min to 7 hours depending upon the network traffic and the
>   demand on our servers.
>
> Event logs show up within 5-7 minutes of occurrence on the device.
>
> Other metrics could take up to 6-7 hours to get processed and show up.
>
> Hope this clarifies.

After 5 hours, it's reflected and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it appears Flurry updates at least twice a day. I'm used to Google Analytics updating alot quicker, but I can't complain to much. Flurry is pretty decent as far as Analytics goes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem too and solved it by replacing all white space characters to underscores in the names of the events and they are appeared after about 5 min.

Incorrect log

> [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"EVENT NAME"];

Correct log

> [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"EVENT_NAME"];

This naming agreement is not mentioned in the FlurryAnalytics' documentation but it worked for me.