# Flurry 4.2.0 not working for Android

Tags: android, flurry-analytics

I am interested in using flurry in my application.
I have implemented the flurry 4.2.0 as mentioned in documents.
and getting following in logcat:

> W/FlurryAgent(28503): FlurryDataSender:  report
>   98ef36e7-8de3-4f37-bb3c-077a95582301 sent.  HTTP response: 200

But unable to trace anything on flurry dashboard.

Here is the code i am using.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
    FlurryAgent.logEvent("My Event");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flurry Integration reflection won't be immediate.

It takes around 24 hours to reflect the changes on Flurry Dashboard.

Check similar answers here :

- [Solution One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545456/flurry-analytics-basic-analytics-issues)
- [Solution Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607172/not-get-report-in-flurry-android-analytics)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are testing in this way!

Once you have integrated Events into your code, you’ll of course want to test that they are firing properly.

The first place to check in the Flurry portal for Event data in your testing sessions is the Event Logs. To go to this section, select your app in the Flurry portal and select “Events” from the left navigation menu, then click “Event Logs”. Session data hits this section first and subsequently populates in the associated charts in the portal.

Event Logs should update within minutes of your test session. You will see the timestamp of the session, the device it came from, and a list of all the Events (and associated parameters) triggered during the session.